# gRPC giving linkage errors in c++

Tags: c++11, grpc, protobuf-c

I am writing a program using gRPC in the language c++. I have installed gRPC using the command `brew install grpc` on a MacOS I also have the most up to date version of `protobuf`. When I create a basic program using gRPC I compile them using the following commands:

`protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --cpp_out=$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/test.proto`
Which creates the `test.pb.h` and `test.pb.cc` files

Then the command `protoc -I . --grpc_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=/usr/local/Cellar/grpc/1.45.2/bin/grpc_cpp_plugin test.proto` which creates the `test.pb.h` and `test.pb.cc` files

I then run the command `g++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ test.cpp test.grpc.pb.cc -L/usr/local/lib -lprotobuf` to compile, where the main c++ file is `test.cpp` I then get some of the following linkage errors:

```
"grpc::ClientContext::ClientContext()", referenced from:
      MathTestClient::sendRequest(int, int) in test-e2eddc.o
  "grpc::ClientContext::~ClientContext()", referenced from:
      MathTestClient::sendRequest(int, int) in test-e2eddc.o
  "grpc::CreateChannel(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<grpc::ChannelCredentials> const&)", referenced from:
      Run() in test-e2eddc.o
  "grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials()", referenced from:
      Run() in test-e2eddc.o
  "mathtest::MathRequest::MathRequest(google::protobuf::Arena*, bool)", referenced from:
      mathtest::MathRequest::MathRequest() in test-e2eddc.o
  "mathtest::MathRequest::~MathRequest()", referenced from:
      MathTestClient::sendRequest(int, int) in test-e2eddc.o
```

Which makes sense, judging based off the fact that in the file `grcpp/impl/codgen/client_context.h` the linkage errors would obviously be there because client context is defined as the following:

```
class ClientContext {
 public:
  ClientContext();
  ~ClientContext();
```

or with the `CreateChannel` function it is defined in `create_channel.h` file as

```
std::shared_ptr<Channel> CreateChannel(
    const grpc::string& target,
    const std::shared_ptr<ChannelCredentials>& creds);
```

In my main c++ file, I only use the following include from gRPC: `#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>`

Are there other include files from gRPC that I need to include which define these functions?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring out my problem if anyone else has installed grpc the same way using homebrew as I did. make sure that on top of the `brew install grpc` command is run that the commands `brew install protobuf` and `brew install abseil`

Next is to find out the paths of all of these using the commands `brew info grpc`, `brew info protobuf` and `brew info abseil` for myself personally the paths are:

`/usr/local/Cellar/abseil/20211102.0`

`/usr/local/Cellar/grpc/1.45.2`

`/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/3.19.4`

Then the `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` needs to be setup, if this does not already exist and there is an error if you run `echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH` you can run `brew install pkg-config` the `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` is defined by all the previous paths, with the added path of `/lib/pkgconfig` which then the `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` can be defined as

`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/grpc/1.45.2/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/3.19.4/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Cellar/abseil/20211102.0/lib/pkgconfig`

After that is all done, and you have the main c++ file and the proto file, mine were named `test.cpp` and `test.proto` respectively, the following commands can be run to make it compile correctly and be able to get and then run `./test`

```
>>> protoc --cpp_out=. test.proto
>>> g++ -std=c++11 `pkg-config --cflags protobuf grpc`  -c -o test.pb.o >>> test.pb.cc
>>> protoc --grpc_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen->>> grpc=/usr/local/Cellar/grpc/1.45.2/bin/grpc_cpp_plugin test.proto
>>> g++ -std=c++11 `pkg-config --cflags protobuf grpc`  -c -o test.grpc.pb.o test.grpc.pb.cc
>>> g++ -std=c++11 `pkg-config --cflags protobuf grpc`  -c -o test.o test.cpp
>>> g++ test.pb.o test.grpc.pb.o test.o -L/usr/local/lib `pkg-config --libs >>> protobuf grpc++` -lgrpc++_reflection -ldl -o test
>>> rm test.grpc.pb.cc test.pb.cc
```